# Image not Aligning in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, javascript, google-earth-engine

A raster dataset in Earth Engine is not aligning properly to the continent. However, a different raster from the same project database does align properly. This is causing issues for down-stream clipping and exporting. I'm assuming there was an issue reprojecting the source data into Earth Engine.

Can anyone provide insight as to how I can fix this CRS/alignment issue?

I looked into similar issues at [Shapefile not projecting properly in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/251259/67264) and [LSIB feature does not align with island boundary in Google Earth Engine?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/312685/67264) but they are both unresolved and deal with shapefiles, not rasters.

Properly aligned raster (GIMP ocean mask):

[image: Correct]

Bad projection (GIMP DEM):

[image: Bad]

```
// Generate water+ice and DEM layers
var ICE = ee.Image('OSU/GIMP/2000_ICE_OCEAN_MASK');
var DEM = ee.Image("OSU/GIMP/DEM");

var ICEParams = {
  min: 0,
  max: 1,
  opacity: 1,
  palette: ['#0000ff', '#00ff00','#007f30','#30b855','#ff0000','#ffff00','#ffffff']
};
var DEMParams = {
      min: 0,
      max: 2000,
      opacity: 0.5,
      palette: ['#0000ff', '#00ff00','#007f30','#30b855','#ff0000','#ffff00','#ffffff']
    };

Map.addLayer(ICE.select("ice_mask"), ICEParams, "Ice");
Map.addLayer(ICE.select("ocean_mask"), ICEParams, "Ocean");
Map.addLayer(DEM, DEMParams, "Elevation");
```

Comment: I feel like this may be a data issue. The transforms are slightly different between the datasets but setting one to the other doesn't fix the problem (if one was mis-defined), and they are too large to fully reproject. I would contact the data providers directly (OSU), just to check if they believe the rasters should indeed exactly overlap.

Comment: I downloaded this project's DEM dataset from the NSIDC website, and interestingly enough I can clip it to my ROI, and everything projects and overlaps properly. I think it must be a transformation issue on the Earth Engine side.